# Is unsupervised commercial kosher food OK?

Tags: kashrut-kosher

Say a Jew starts selling food commercially.  He keeps strict kosher, but does not buy kosher supervision to keep his prices down.  His customers are his many friends, who know him well and trust him, and his business flourishes by word of mouth. He follows all secular laws and does not officially claim kashrut.

Question: Is there a halacha that says observant Jews must not buy food from him?

Comment: Until roughly 100 years ago this was how kosher restaurants worked

Comment: I saw one such restaurant in Jerusalem, a falafel place, with a sign saying there was no formal supervision but he was buying all ingredients from supermarket X with supervision Y. And the place was full of religious Jews eating. Note however that preparing falafel is quite simple and there is not so much room for mistakes once you use kosher ingredients. Note also your scenario happens every Shabbat at thousands of houses across the world where friends host friends without supervision

Comment: @mbloch -- That's why I said "commercial".  In a private home no one is selling.

Comment: Vote to reopen- the dupe question doesn't seem to have a definitive answer